# What data is included when MySQL creates a temporary table?

Tags: mysql, select, varchar, temp-tables

I have been reading about VARCHAR fields being converted to CHAR fields whenever MySQL generates a temporary table.

If I have the following table...

- Excess of 100K rows
- A dozen VARCHAR columns set to real lengths (e.g., 10 for phone numbers)
- 5 VARCHAR columns set to 15K (with lengths that could be as short as 20 but up to 15K worse case)

And, let's say I have this query...

- Returns multiple columns including the VARCHARs
- JOIN'd with a half-dozen other tables (*not* on VARCHAR columns)
- Sorts the rows by date and numeric id (i.e., *not* on the VARCHAR columns)
- Has a WHERE clause that does *not* include the VARCHAR fields
- Has a LIMIT of 12 rows

When MySQL creates a temporary table, in order to sort and occasionally group (in some cases), what ends up in the temporary table?

For instance, does the table only include the columns necessary to choose which rows to return (i.e., those specified in WHERE and ORDER BY clauses), followed by the database engine determining the 12 rows in the LIMIT, and then reading the data for just those 12 rows? Or, is a larger chunk of data included in the temporary table (e.g., all potential rows including the lengthy VARCHAR columns)?

Comment: do you generate the temporary table with this statement?
    `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (count int);`

Comment: @Matteo: No, I am not explicitly creating a temporary table. As I understand (or misunderstand) it, a temporary table is implicitly created whenever my query sorts or groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If temporary table fits [memory restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size), it is created using [HEAP (Memory engine)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html). All limitations apply. If it grows too large, server converts it into [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) temporary table on disk.

Comment: Can you prove this via documentation?

Comment: @FractalizeR: Could you explain that in more elementary terms? Basically, I'm wondering whether the presence or length of VARCHAR fields affect performance or memory when those VARCHAR columns are not the basis of WHERE, ORDER BY or GROUP BY clauses. In my simplistic logic, there'd be no need to include data that didn't affect the selection of rows until those rows (e.g., in my case, the 12 specified by the LIMIT statement) were determined. I imagine (again simplistically) that the data I wanted returned (including the content of the VARCHAR columns) would then be read for only those 12 rows.

Comment: @LeeB. Well, basically, it means, that when mysql builds temporary table in memory and that table has columns VARCHAR(X1), VARCHAR(X2)..., every data line of that table will occupy about X1+X2+...+Xn bytes. Memory for VARCHAR columns in temporary tables is reserved like for CHAR columns (fixed size).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation when I tried to find out if just having a `TEXT` or `BLOB` in a table is necessary to force a disk-based temporary table when MySQL has to make a temporary table or that it is also based on whether that column is in the query (`SELECT` or `WHERE` clause).

This was the query (`posts.body` is of the type `TEXT`)

```
SELECT * FROM posts p LEFT JOIN user u ON p.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN setting s ON u.id = s.user_id WHERE (p.title LIKE '%search%' AND (p.status = 'PUBLISH' AND p.date <= 1368441957)) GROUP BY u.id LIMIT 5
```

I saw that running this increments the `Created_tmp_disk_tables` variable. So I changed the query to

```
SELECT p.id FROM posts p LEFT JOIN user u ON p.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN setting s ON u.id = s.user_id WHERE (p.title LIKE '%search%' AND (p.status = 'PUBLISH' AND p.date <= 1368441957)) GROUP BY u.id LIMIT 5
```

And interestingly the counter didn't increase. However, the MySQL documentation mentions the following which is different from my inference

> Some conditions prevent the use of an in-memory temporary table, in which case the server uses an on-disk table instead:
>
> Presence of a BLOB or TEXT column in the table
>
> ...